# administrative abilities using OAuth 2

Tags: events, c#-4.0, calendar, bulkinsert, administrator

One of my clients (state public defenders office) has asked me to write a system to update people's (laywer's) calendars (google for govt, calendar) on a daily basis, from data pulled from the Circuit Court (a seperate agency) via web services. Currently the defenders office is using Visual Studio 2001 beta for most of their applications, but will allow me to develop something new in VS2010 and SQL Server 2008 r2. Currently, they pull data from these web services and put them in a SQL Server database, to enable displaying this info on their web site.

I can't seem to find any demo, nor source code, in Dot.Net, to connect to Google Calendar as an administrator, and insert calendar events about upcoming case and trial appearences.

Another agency (The District Attorney's office) has written an application to pull data from the aforementioned web services and create calendar events in MS Exchange and MS OutLook. It is hoped that the defender's office can do the same with Google for Govt.

The network admin there told me to look at GAM (python app). I'm hoping to find C Sharp examples rather than try to translate Python to C Sharp, line by line.

Randy

Answer (score 0):

Check out the official [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)!

There are client libraries for .net

It also has a get started section on the .net download area. You'll probably need access setup before hand to make the changes though.

Comment: Been there, done that... The question is... in Dot.Net, how to connect to Google Calendar as an administrator that will allow insert and editing. Everything IS already setup because GAM works from the network admin's workstation.

Comment: What happens in the "Task" sample code is... If I run the sample application while not logged into my Gmail account, OAuth pops open a Gmail login asking for my gmail userid and password, then the console app prompts for my Client ID and Client secret, then it pops open another browser screen and asks for the API Key. 

There has to be a less convoluted way to get authenticated... (as an admin)  Doing the above only gave me access to my "tasks", but probably not others.

Comment: Also, I'd like this authentication to persist, so that the C# app can run 24/7, 365 days a year (except for periodic maintenance), flawlessly enough so that attorneys won't miss any court appearances. 

  Is this possible, or should I be looking at a different route?